# Как добавить правильнее текст с переносами строк и различными символами в переменную в Makefile?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, environment-variables

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как добавить правильнее текст с переносами строк и различными символами в переменную в Makefile?

сейчас символы обрезаются и переносы с отступами не учитываются..

Пример текста для записи в переменную в Makefile

```html
VARIABLE="<?php

          namespace App\Form\${CLASS_NAME};

          use App\Form\${CLASS_NAME}\Request\${CLASS_NAME}CreateRequest;
          use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
          use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
          use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

          class ${CLASS_NAME}Type extends AbstractType
          {
              public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
              {
                  $builder
                      ->add('name', null, [
                          'label' => 'Название'
                      ]);
              }

              public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
              {
                  $resolver->setDefaults([
                      'data_class' => ${CLASS_NAME}Request::class,
                  ]);
              }
          }
"
```

да возможно выглядит костыльно.. но все же?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

предуведомление: в ответе идёт речь о программе [gnu/make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

---

для многострочных текстов [лучше использовать директиву `define`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html):

```
define переменная
многострочный текст
с символами $ которые надо удвоить: $$
  и отступами.
если обратный слэш нужен в конце строки, \
то _после_ него
надо поставить пробел. вот так:\ 
тогда и слэш не будет интерпретирован
как символ разрыва строки.
endef
```

вывести значение такой переменной на экран проще всего с помощью [функции `info`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html#Make-Control-Functions):

```
цель:
  $(info $(переменная))
```

результат:

```
$ make цель
многострочный текст
с символами которые надо удвоить: $
  и отступами.
если обратный слэш нужен в конце строки, то _после_ него
надо поставить пробел. вот так:\ 
тогда и слэш не будет интерпретирован
как символ разрыва строки.
```

---

а если значение такой переменной надо записать в файл, то проще всего воспользоваться [функцией `file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html#File-Function):

```
цель:
  $(file > имя.файла,$(переменная))
```

имя файла, конечно, можно указать и с помощью переменной (в том числе и любой подходящей [«автоматической», типа `$@`, `$%` и т.п.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)):

```
имя = имя.файла
цель:
  $(file > $(имя),$(переменная))
```

Comment: Спасибо все хорошо расписали, но не могли бы еще подсказать где у меня ошибка в синтаксисе? http://i.imgur.com/oKj7iW5.png http://i.imgur.com/Y04LdWB.png

Comment: опечатка у меня: не вписал саму файловую операцию (в данном случае — `>`). исправил в ответе.